# Test Authorize.Net Recurring Payments By silent Post ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb, silent-post

I have been using Authorize.Net payment gateway in my asp.net application.
I am using a **developer account** to test the subscriptions created from Authorize.Net ARB (SOAP).The subscription is created for the accounts but i am not able to **test the results** by using the silent post method **for the future recurring payments related to an account**.

http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/

I have read this post , and its really helpful;
But is there any way where I can receive response data from Authorize.net for the future payments of an account created from my authorize.net developer account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer accounts don't actually process payments including scheduled recurring billing payments. They just allow you to verify that the API call was successful. So there is no real way, using a developer account, to test Silent Post with ARB.

Comment: Okay ..thank you John...Your responses really have been helpful to me.